# How to define test task

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code to develop a simple project. I've created some unit tests (xUnit.net) and I would like create a test task to execute them. The idea is to run tests whenever I hit `Ctrl+Shift+T`.

However, I am not able to figure out how to define test tasks. What is the correct way to achieve that?

Comment: To use the shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+T` you have to define a task with `"taskName"="test"`. If the execution of the test-suite can be done with a single command, you can follow the task.json examples.

Comment: Have you seen any documentation for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides naming the task to execute test you can set the `isTestCommand` property to true. Something like

```
{
   ...
   tasks: [{
      "taskName": "myTestTask",
      "isTestCommand": true,
      ...
   }]
}
```

This will also bind myTestTask to Ctrl+Shift+T

Comment: "isTestCommand": true was deprecated on Visual Studio Code version 1.14

Answer (score 4):

Looks like they changed the default behavior of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keybinding in recent versions to reopen the last tab closed (like many browsers support). To view your current Keyboard Bindings, select the following menu option:

`File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`

If you want to change the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keybinding back to issuing your default test task, simply change the value of the `command` property in the following object:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+t", "command": "workbench.action.reopenClosedEditor" }
```

to be: `workbench.action.tasks.test`, or you can assign the testing task to a different keybinding by adding the following line to your Default Keyboard Shortcuts config file:

```
{ "key": "<your keybinding here>", "command": "workbench.action.tasks.test" }
```

Answer (score 3):

This has changed in the latest version of VS Code (1.47.0)

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Run tests",
      "group": "test", // <-- this will add this task to 'Run test task'
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "npm test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this link it's self explanatory

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks

Create a tasks.json file inside .vscode

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "MY-COMMAND-FOR-RUNNING-TEST",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

if you have configured **npm test**

```
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "command": "npm",
        "args": ["test"],
        "isShellCommand": true
    }
```

if you have configured **gulp** with a **test task**

```
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "command": "gulp",
        "args": ["test"],
        "isShellCommand": true
    }
```